# Will C/C++ libraries work on Android Phone

Tags: android

Does anyone have any experience using JNI to call native C/C++ libraries in Android? Is the environment suitable for running C/C++ libraries and if so is there anything specific about the environment which you need to accommodate?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that Android provides only a subset of the standard C++ runtime library. For example, Android [does not support exceptions](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/89db67ed1fbf6450) in native code. I think there are other restrictions as well.

---

One complication is that, while Android itself might include many native libraries, only some of them are considered stable enough to link against. The [Android NDK page](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/sdk/ndk/1.5_r1/index.html) lists the libraries which are safe.

- libc (C library) headers
- libm (math library) headers
- JNI interface headers
- libz (Zlib compression) headers
- liblog (Android logging) header
- A Minimal set of headers for C++ support

If your C library only uses those, you should be fine. C++ support sounds a little spottier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel. I've also just read that the native Dalvik core code is written in C/C++ and also uses the JNI bridge. This is similar to the work I want to do so I'm hopeful that I can write JNI calls to C libraries in my Android app.

Answer (score 1):

For a good example of C and Java integration, check this out:

https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator

Untar the files and you can find a jni/termExec.cpp - which uses normal C API like "exec()", "fork()", and "open(/dev/ptmx)" to implement terminal emulation (http://linux.die.net/man/4/ptmx).

Looking up the jni/Android.mk file, and u can see that the cpp is compiled as a library -  libandroidterm.

And then the java application (src/jackpal/androidterm/Exec.java) will load the library via System.loadLibrary("androidterm").

I think this application provide a small enough example for u to extend whichever way u like - either the cpp or the java file.   (The cpp file is basically C-based, not C plus plus).

And remember the mapping between them, for example here it is:

```
static JNINativeMethod method_table[]
= {
    { "createSubprocess", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[I)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;",
        (void*) android_os_Exec_createSubProcess },
    { "setPtyWindowSize", "(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;IIII)V",
        (void*) android_os_Exec_setPtyWindowSize},
    { "waitFor", "(I)I",
        (void*) android_os_Exec_waitFor},
    { "close", "(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;)V",
        (void*) android_os_Exec_close} };
```

Answer (score 0):

for a C library, you shouldn't have any trouble. a C++ library might be more fun if it uses much of the standard library, because most of the C++ standard library is missing, but you can always supply your own "mini-STL". that's basically how external/webkit works.

much of Android's java.util.regex, java.nio.charset, java.util, and java.text are implemented by calling ICU4C, for example. (the library's in external/icu4c and the JNI is in dalvik/libcore/icu/src/main/native.) a mix of ICU's C and C++ interfaces are used, so you can rest assured this stuff gets quite a good workout on a daily basis ;-)